# How to declare a variable as currency in VB 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm not too up to date with the latest VB software but when I try to declare a variable both globally and locally as currency it does not recognize it. Any info is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currency is no longer available, and has been replaced by [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Classes come pretty cheap in .NET.  If it was valuable to your application, you could write your own custom currency class that uses the decimal type to store the value.  You can create an abstract currency class and then other classes that inherit it and have specific implementations or properties or specify some kind of conversion methods between themselves and other know currency units (perhaps as an enum of sorts).

```vb
Public MustInherit Class Currency
    Public Value As Decimal
    Public Unit As String
End Class

Public Class Dollars : Inherits Currency

End Class
```